# Drawing a backward arrow in a flow chart using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the arrow shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes}
               
\begin{document}
 \noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{   \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 5mm and 12mm, 
  block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=#1,
                  minimum height=3em, text width=6em, align=center},
block/.default = white,
decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=white!20,
    text width=6em, align=center, minimum height=3em},
every edge/.append style = {draw=black!50, thick, -Latex}
                    ]
\node [block] (A) {Initial step};
\node [block, right =of A] (B) {Second step};
\node [block, above right = of B] (C) {Third step};
\node [block, below right = of B] (D) {4th step};
\node [decision, below right = of C] (E) {Is  condition met?};

\node [block,  right = of E] (F) {Take an action};

\path   (A) edge (B);
\draw[thick,anchor=west]   (B.+5)  edge  (C.west);         
\draw[thick,anchor=west]   (B.-5)  edge  (D.west);    
\draw[thick]   (C.+5)  edge  (E.-227.5);         
\draw[thick]   (D.+5)  edge  (E.227.5);
\draw[thick, anchor=south]   (E)  edge node{Yes} (F);

\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

I am adding the following line, however, it gives me an error.

```
\draw[thick]  (F.north) | -- ++(2,0) | (A.north);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you want is something like

```
\draw[thick, ->]  (F.north) -- ++(0,3) -| (A.north);
```

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes}
               
\begin{document}
 \noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{   \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 5mm and 12mm, 
  block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=#1,
                  minimum height=3em, text width=6em, align=center},
block/.default = white,
decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=white!20,
    text width=6em, align=center, minimum height=3em},
every edge/.append style = {draw=black!50, thick, -Latex}
                    ]
\node [block] (A) {Initial step};
\node [block, right =of A] (B) {Second step};
\node [block, above right = of B] (C) {Third step};
\node [block, below right = of B] (D) {4th step};
\node [decision, below right = of C] (E) {Is  condition met?};

\node [block,  right = of E] (F) {Take an action};

\path   (A) edge (B);
\draw[thick,anchor=west]   (B.+5)  edge  (C.west);         
\draw[thick,anchor=west]   (B.-5)  edge  (D.west);    
\draw[thick]   (C.+5)  edge  (E.-227.5);         
\draw[thick]   (D.+5)  edge  (E.227.5);
\draw[thick, anchor=south]   (E)  edge node{Yes} (F);

\draw[thick, ->]  (F.north) -- ++(0,3) -| (A.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on my answer on your previous question. Feedback arrow is drawn in two parts: from the last node F to aux coordinate placed above node C and from it to the first node A:

```
\draw[arr]  (F) |- (aux) -| (A);
```

For this is defined new style `arr` which is used in above command and in `every edge` style (used for drawing connections between nodes). In the below proposed solution is not used `resizebox`, rather are reduced `node distance` and `text width` of nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
%\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 2mm and 8.8mm,
     arr/.style = {draw=black!50, thick, -Latex},
    base/.style = {draw, font=\small,
                   minimum height=2em, text width=4em, align=center},
   block/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=#1},
 block/.default = white,
decision/.style = {diamond, base, inner xsep=-3pt},
decision/.default = white,
every edge/.append style = {arr}
                    ]
\node [block] (A) {Initial step};
\node [block, right =of A] (B) {The next step};
\node [block, above right = of B] (C) {The third step};
\node [block, below right = of B] (D) {The fourth step};
\node [decision, below right = of C] (E) {Is condition met?};
\node [block, right =of E] (F) {The an action};
%
\coordinate[above=of C] (aux);
\path   (A) edge (B)
        (B.+5) edge (C.west)
        (B.-5) edge (D.west)
        (C.east) edge (E.north west)
        (D.east) edge (E.south west)
        (E)      edge (F);
\draw[arr]  
        (F) |- (aux) -| (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]